# Recording output from loops in R

Tags: r, loops, record, palindrome

I am doing an exercise in my R class, and I hope you can help. The task is to create my own script that determines whether or not a number is a palindrome. My idea was to create a repetition structure that records each digit in a number of any size, compares those digits in order, and then makes a call as to whether the number is a palindrome or not.

So far, I thought I could use the "for" command to break the number down, like this:

```
# Initialize
Number <- 242   
Number

N <- nchar(Number)    
N

# Find numbers and digits
if (Number == 0) {
    print ("Number must be greater than 0")
}

if (Number < 0) {
    print ("Number must be greater than 0")
}

for (i in 1:N) {
    print (Number)
    Digit <- Number %/% 10^(N-1)
    print (Digit)
    Number <- Number %% 10^(N-1)
    N <- N-1
}
```

The problem, though, is that since this structure overwrites the variables in each loop, I cannot print all the digits out separately once the loop is done. Can I command R to print out and record the digits produced in each loop, so that they can be compared to each other downstream and used to assess whether the original number was a palindrome or not? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: `strsplit("242","")` or as a vector: `unlist(strsplit("242",""))`

Answer (score 2):

There's better ways of checking for palindrome-ness in R, for which you should see the other answers. For your specific problem of keeping track of things during a for loop, one approach is to make a vector that's as long as the for loop and assign to the `i`th element of the vector in the `i`th iteration of the loop.

```
Number <- 12345
N <- nchar(Number)
backwardsDigits <- numeric(N) ## a vector of numerics of length N
for (i in N:1) {
    backwardsDigits[i] <- Number %/% 10^(i-1)
    Number <- Number %% 10^(i-1)
}

backwardsDigits

all(backwardsDigits == rev(backwardsDigits))
```

You could use `forwardsDigits` instead by writing to `forwardsDigits[N - i + 1]` in the loop. You don't really need to `print` anything during the loop, though it can be helpful for debugging.

Comment: that probably worked for you because i was 1 from the previous iteration of the loop :)

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail suggested, there is another (perhaps more intuitive way) to do this.

First, let's convert the number 117711 to a string and split it up.

```
charsplit <- strsplit(as.character(117712), "")

[[1]]
[1] "1" "1" "7" "7" "1" "2"
```

Then, we'll take it out of list form and reverse it

```
revchar <- rev(unlist(charsplit))

[1] "2" "1" "7" "7" "1" "1"
```

Finally, we'll paste these together and convert them into a number:

```
palinum <- as.numeric(paste(revchar, collapse=""))

[1] "217711"
```

We can then check if they're identical:

```
117712 == palinum

[1] FALSE
```

We can even write a function to do it for us.

```
is.palindrome <- function(number){
  charsplit <- strsplit(as.character(number), "")
  revchar <- rev(unlist(charsplit))
  palinum <- as.numeric(paste(revchar, collapse=""))

  number==palinum
}

is.palindrome(117712)
[1] FALSE

is.palindrome(117711)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You could also use `identical` to check if the two vectors are the same forwards and backwards without having to do the paste & collapse step. I.e. `charsplit <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(10200201), ""));
identical(charsplit,rev(charsplit))`

Comment: And really only need to compare the first `floor(n/2)` and last `floor(n/2)`

Comment: @thelatemail An excellent point. This has the added benefit of allowing it to work for characters as well. Feel free to adjust it.